# PHP MongoDB exception (Error handling)

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a PHP platform where user write mongodb query like picture below

[image]

and following code print result as a table

```
$m = new MongoClient();
$db = $m->Forensic;
$coll= $db->mobile_data;

if (isset($_POST['txt_area']) && !empty($_POST['txt_area'])) { 


    $d = ($_POST['txt_area']);
    $p = json_decode($d);
    $user_code = $coll->find($p);
```

When I type correct code system able to ouput all my result but if I write query wrong I am getting error message like

```
Warning: MongoCollection::find(): expects parameter 1 to be an array or object, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\reports5.php on line 126
```

to catch that error i have tried following try catch code but no luck

```
 try {
if (isset($_POST['txt_area']) && !empty($_POST['txt_area'])) { 


    $d = ($_POST['txt_area']);
    $p = json_decode($d);
    $user_code = $coll->find($p);

    $NumberOfRow2 = $user_code->count();

    $user_code->sort(array('Chat_group' => -1, 'Instant_Message' => 1 ));

}
}

catch (MongoCursorException $e) {
    echo "error message: ".$e->getMessage()."\n";
    echo "error code: ".$e->getCode()."\n";
}

catch (MongoException $e) 
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
catch(MongoResultException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    $res = $e->getDocument();
    var_dump($res);
}
```

what would be the best way to catch above error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning you're seeing is PHP complaining that `$coll->find($p);` expects `$p` to be either array or object while it's `null`. Quoting [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) documentation:

> NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit.

So a proper way to defend against warning would be:

```
$p = json_decode($d);
if ($p === null) {
    echo "Provided query is invalid!";
} else {
    // do your logic
}
```